# Builds are blocked in the TFS build controller

Tags: tfs

I have setup a continuous integration build in TFS
And it was working fine but since the previous week all builds are blocked in the TFS build controller, all builds are queued and blocked on the SERVERBUILD-IMS controller.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: Is the build service actually running?

Comment: Are you getting errors on the build controller or build agent in the event log?

Comment: Please share more related info such as error message ,what did you try, the version of TFS to narrow down the issue..

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to TFS Administration Console, and check build service status. Check whether the build controller and build agent are Ready. Try to restart the build service.
2. If the build service is running. Try to remove the Build service feature and re-configure it, to see whether the issue persists.